# How to set random color box in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, random, colors, themes

Good Morning, I am working on my wordpress web-page, which is made of image-boxes and they are changed to one-color background boxes with text on hover. See example here: http://www.top-news.6f.sk/.
I want make this boxes to have random color background or random color from list of colors.
I found out that the color of these boxes isnt set in .css file but its probably generated by some php file or function. (If u inspect source code you cand find that there is generated some css style inside, so if i put this code in my stelysheet.css it still wont work because it is overrided.
Can you give me any clues where to find a code where can i change the color of these boxes? Then I would be able to rewrite it to random color.
Thanks

Comment: `grep -r` . or you can put an !important in the css rule to force an override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override inline styles, in your style.css, use !important.

Similar to :

background-color: #fff !important;

Comment: thanks that helped! However i didnt realized that the random color will be applied to all boxes. Is there any clue how to specify random color for each box ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a random background color

```
 <?php $hex = dechex(rand(0,255)) . dechex(rand(0,255)) . dechex(rand(0,255)); ?>
```

and then you’d use the following in your body tag:

```
<body BGCOLOR=“#<?php echo($hex);?>”>
```